# Using Contextual filter in Filtering attached view

Tags: nodes

Suppose I have these two node types, with the following fields:

#### Port

Name
Description

#### Voyage

Name
Port1
Port2
Port3

I used [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) to link the port fields in Voyage to the node ID of the Port nodes.

Now, in the page of any port node, I need to attach a display of voyages names that has calls to that port. How can I achieve that in Views with EVA?

Or to put it logically: "SELECT Name FROM Voyage WHERE (port1 = (urlid) or port2 = (urlid) or port3 = (urlid));" urlid is the ID of the port we are getting through the argument (contextual filter).

I have used contextual filter, but there seems to be no way to use OR in contextual filters...

Answer (score 6):

The contextual filters belong to the first filter group so if you click the little arrow besides the Filter "add" then choose "and / or" then you can switch the operator of the first group to OR.

Comment: the problem is that in Druapl 7, "contextual filter" is separated from "Filter" and unlike Filter,  "contextual filter" does not have the OR option

Comment: Follow the instructions. They are correct. The instructions say click the arrow besides Filter and not Contextual Filter.

Comment: I clicked the and/or choice beside the filter, and I got the screenshot: [link](http://oi56.tinypic.com/ao2495.jpg)
I don't see how i can make an OR operation with the contextual filters I have, these only show the normal filter arguments and setting an or operator between them, won't solve my problem

Comment: if you change the Operator: AND on this screen to Operator: OR it should change contextual filters to OR.

Comment: But it will affect the other filter, i need the and between "pubished" and "type=voyage"

Comment: Then this group should contain status = 0 (unpublished) alone, create a second filter group with published and type='voyage', use and between filter groups. The SQLis SELECT Name FROM Voyage WHERE (port1 = (urlid) or port2 = (urlid) or port3 = (urlid) or status = 0 ) AND (type = 'voyage' AND status = 1). Obviously if status = 0 the second half will fail.

Comment: Thanks, that workaround makes a lot of sense to me. But what is happening is that it is only considering port1! and ignoring all my other ports. this is a screenshot to see my view settings
[link](http://i51.tinypic.com/2cerkk.png)

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me at all. You are suggesting that be setting the condition to OR in one of the filter groups, this somehow affects the conditional filters? You can have multiple filter groups each with their own AND/OR status. I can see no way how this relates to conditional filter at all.